# Organizar grupos

Tags: java

Eu não consegui achar a lógica para implementar isso.

Então, vou explicar de outra forma para melhor entendimento:

O algoritmo combina 10 números em conjuntos de 6, que dá um total de 210 volantes. Sendo que, eu preciso colocar uma condição para garantir que não mostrem os conjuntos no qual se repetem 5 dos 6 números.

Exemplo: Eu tenho esta combinação 10 números em um conjunto de 6.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6  //
1 2 3 4 5 7 
1 2 3 4 5 8 
1 2 3 4 5 9 
1 2 3 4 5 10 
1 2 3 4 6 7 
1 2 3 4 6 8
1 2 3 4 6 9
1 2 3 4 6 10
1 2 3 4 7 8  //
.......
```

Sendo que, 5 dos 6 números do conjunto sempre se repetem. Então eu preciso que o algoritmo me mostre apenas os conjuntos que não tenham os 5 números repetidos. Conforme eu destaquei com `//`.

```
01  02  03  04  05  06 ; 
01  02  03  04  07  08 ;
01  02  03  04  09  10 ;
01  02  03  05  07  09 ;
01  02  03  05  08  10 ;
01  02  03  06  07  10 ;
01  02  03  06  08  09 ;
01  02  04  05  07  10 ;
01  02  04  05  08  09 ;
01  02  04  06  07  09 ;
01  02  04  06  08  10 ;
01  02  05  06  07  08 ;
01  02  05  06  09  10 ;
01  02  07  08  09  10 ;
03  04  05  06  07  08 ;
03  04  05  06  09  10 ;
03  04  07  08  09  10 ;
05  06  07  08  09  10 ;
```

```java
package jogo;

import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Combinacoes {

    private int numeros[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};  
    private int quantidade = 6;  
    private int resultado[] = new int[6]; 
    private ArrayList<String>aParsear = new ArrayList<String>();
    private HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
    private int count = 0;
    private String[] temp;

    private void busca(int inicio,int fim, int profundidade){  

        if ( (profundidade + 1) >= quantidade)  
            for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){  
                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];  
                // faz alguma coisa com um dos resultados possiveis  
                count++;  

                String tmp = ""+  resultado[0] + ", "
                        + resultado[1] + ", "
                        + resultado[2] + ", "
                        + resultado[3] + ", "
                        + resultado[4] + ", "
                        + resultado[5] + ""; 
                System.out.println(tmp);
                aParsear.add(tmp);
            }  
        else  
            for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){  
                resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];  
                busca(x + 1,fim + 1,profundidade + 1);  
            }  
    }  

    private void parsearListaGerada(){
        Iterator<String> it = aParsear.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            String tmp = it.next();
            int[]valoresInteiros = new int[6];
            String[]valoresLiterais = tmp.split(",");
            for(int i = 0;i < valoresLiterais.length;i++){
                valoresInteiros[i]= Integer.parseInt(valoresLiterais[i].trim());
            }
            int chave=0;
            for(int j=0;j < valoresInteiros.length;j++){
                chave+=((j+1)*valoresInteiros[j]);
            }
            if(map.containsKey(chave))
                System.out.println("ger,"+tmp);
                map.put(chave,tmp);
            }

            System.out.println("Tamanho final:"+map.size());
            System.out.println("Resultado final");
            for(String valor:map.values())
                System.out.println(valor);            

        }



    public static void main(String args[]){  

        Combinacoes comb = new Combinacoes();  
        comb.busca(0, (10-6), 0);  
        System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + comb.count); 
        comb.parsearListaGerada();

    }  

}
```

Comment: O seu problema provavelmente é simples e fácil de resolver. Entretanto a descrição que você deu ficou super confusa e não entendi nada. Tentei editá-la para ver se assim, faria mais sentido para mim (e para os outros também). Com a edição deu para melhorar um pouco, mas ainda não entendo o que você está querendo fazer.

Answer (score 2):

## Simplificando o código

Vamos dar uma olhada no seu código.

1. Veja este import:

   ```
   import java.awt.List;
   ```

   Não é essa a lista que você quer importar. Você não está utilizando esse `List` para nada, mas o que você queria de fato importar é o `java.util.List`.
2. Essas variáveis:

   ```
       private ArrayList<String>aParsear = new ArrayList<String>();
       private HashMap<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
   ```

   Você pode utilizar a sintaxe do diamante para evitar ter que repetir os genéricos. Além disso, é uma boa prática codificar para uma interface e não uma implementação. Ou seja, usar `List` e `Map` (do pacote `java.util`) como tipos ao invés de `ArrayList` e `HashMap`. Eis o que seria o resultado:

   ```
       private List<String> aParsear = new ArrayList<>();
       private Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
   ```
3. Vamos ver a forma que você transforma o array em `String`:

   ```
                  String tmp = ""+  resultado[0] + ", "
                           + resultado[1] + ", "
                           + resultado[2] + ", "
                           + resultado[3] + ", "
                           + resultado[4] + ", "
                           + resultado[5] + "";
   ```

   Isso ficaria bem mais simples e bem melhor se fosse assim, além de não depender do tamanho do array estar fixo em 6:

   ```
                   StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(", ");
                   IntStream.of(resultado).boxed().map(Object::toString).forEach(sj::add);
                   String tmp = sj.toString();
   ```

   Ou então, se você não tiver problemas quanto a alterar um pouco o formato da `String` resultante:

   ```
                   String tmp = Arrays.toString(resultado);
   ```
4. Vejamos o seu `if`:

   ```
           if (...)
               // Um monte de linhas aqui.
           else
               // Mais um monte de linhas aqui.
   ```

   Por favor, use as chaves nesse caso porque é muito fácil você fazer besteiras ao não colocá-las. Por exemplo:

   ```
   if (algumaCoisa)
       System.out.println("Estou dentro do if.");
       System.out.println("Será que ainda estou dentro do if?");
   ```

   Aliás, mais abaixo, o seu código tem esse exato problema:

   ```
               if(map.containsKey(chave))
                   System.out.println("ger,"+tmp);
                   map.put(chave,tmp);
               }
   ```

   Perdi algum tempo para entender o programa por causa desse bloco aí em cima. A identação sugere que o `}` se refere ao `if`, mas na verdade ele é do `while` que está do lado de fora. O fato do código estar identado incorretamente e não utilizar todos os pares de chaves que deveria acaba induzindo quem estiver lendo o código ao erro.
5. Veja o seu laço `while`:

   ```
           Iterator<String> it = aParsear.iterator();

           while(it.hasNext()){
               String tmp = it.next();
   ```

   Não use o `Iterator` diretamente se não tiver um bom motivo para fazê-lo. Prefira o *enhanced-for*:

   ```
           for (String tmp : aParsear) {
   ```
6. A sua lista `aParsear` na verdade consiste de um array que você transforma em `String` para depois transformar de volta em array. Isso é uma gambiarra. Para resolver isso, você pode trocar esse código:

   ```
                   aParsear.add(tmp);
   ```

   Por isso:

   ```
                   aParsear.add(resultado.clone());
   ```

   E com isso, pode eliminar a variável `tmp` do método `busca` se quiser.

   Isso daqui:

   ```
       private ArrayList<String>aParsear = new ArrayList<String>()
   ```

   Fica assim:

   ```
       private List<int[]> aParsear = new ArrayList<>();
   ```

   Você pode então simplificar um monte de coisas no `parsearListaGerada` com isso:

   ```
           for (int[] valoresInteiros : aParsear) {
               String tmp = Arrays.toString(valoresInteiros);
   ```
7. Você pode substituir isso:

   ```
           System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + comb.count);
   ```

   Por isso:

   ```
           System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + comb.aParsear.size());
   ```

   E então isso daqui pode ser apagado:

   ```
                   // faz alguma coisa com um dos resultados possiveis  
                   count++;
   ```

   E isso também:

   ```
       private int count = 0;
       private String[] temp;
   ```
8. Podemos simplificar o seu `if` com os dois `for`s:

   ```
          if ( (profundidade + 1) >= quantidade)  
               for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){
                   resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                   // Algumas coisas.
               }
           else
               for(int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++){
                   resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
                   // Outras coisas.
               }
   ```

   E deixá-lo assim:

   ```
           for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {
               resultado[profundidade] = numeros[x];
               if (profundidade + 1 >= quantidade) {
                   // Algumas coisas.
               } else {
                   // Outras coisas.
               }
           }
   ```
9. Observe que o seu `Map` é utilizado apenas dentro do método `parsearListaGerada` e que após o uso do método, o `Map` não contém nenhuma informação que seja relevante de ser preservada. Assim sendo, coloque o `Map` como uma variável local deste método.
10. Podemos trocar `quantidade` por `resultado.length`, e com isso eliminar essa variável.
11. Prefira usar `(String[] args)` ao invés de `(String args[])`. Assim você preserva o padrão de declaração [tipo da variável antes e nome da variável depois] utilizado em quase todos os outros lugares da linguagem Java. Caso contrário fica uma coisa no formato [uma parte do tipo da variável antes, nome da variável no meio, resto do tipo da variável depois], o que é um tanto confuso. O mesmo vale para transformar `int resultado[]` em `int[] resultado`.
12. Supondo que a lista de números seja sempre 1, 2, 3, 4... então você pode eliminar o array `numeros` e trocar o `numeros[x]` por `x + 1`.
13. Um nome melhor para a sua variável `aParsear` seria `volantes`.
14. Para evitar que o seu programa fique fixo em 10 elementos no jogo com 6 no volante e que você tenha que chamar `comb.buscar(0, (10-6), 0);` no `main`, passando esses números mágicos, você pode introduzir um construtor e um novo método `busca`:

    ```
        private int[] resultado;
        private List<int[]> volantes = new ArrayList<>();

        public Combinacoes(int quantidade) {
            this.resultado = new int[quantidade];
        }

        public void busca(int numeros) {
            busca(0, numeros - resultado.length, 0);
        }
    ```

    E então no seu `main` você faz isso:

    ```
            Combinacoes comb = new Combinacoes(6); 
            comb.busca(10);
    ```

Há ainda algumas outras mudanças possíveis, mas acho que aqui já está de bom tamanho. O código resultante tem exatamente o mesmo comportamento do seu código original da pergunta (com exceção de que ele mostra pares de colchetes para cada sêxtupla na saída). Veja como ficou o seu código:

## Código simplificado

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Combinacoes {

    private int[] resultado;
    private List<int[]> volantes = new ArrayList<>();

    public Combinacoes(int quantidade) {
        this.resultado = new int[quantidade];
    }

    public void busca(int numeros) {
        busca(0, numeros - resultado.length, 0);
    }

    private void busca(int inicio, int fim, int profundidade) {
        for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {
            resultado[profundidade] = x + 1;
            if (profundidade + 1 >= resultado.length) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(resultado));
                volantes.add(resultado.clone());
            } else {
                busca(x + 1, fim + 1, profundidade + 1);
            }
        }
    }  

    private void parsearListaGerada() {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int[] valoresInteiros : volantes) {
            String tmp = Arrays.toString(valoresInteiros);
            int chave = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < valoresInteiros.length; j++) {
                chave += ((j + 1) * valoresInteiros[j]);
            }
            if (map.containsKey(chave)) {
                System.out.println("ger," + tmp);
            }
            map.put(chave, tmp);
        }

        System.out.println("Tamanho final:" + map.size());
        System.out.println("Resultado final");
        for (String valor : map.values()) {
            System.out.println(valor);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Combinacoes comb = new Combinacoes(6);  
        comb.busca(10);  
        System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + comb.aParsear.size()); 
        comb.parsearListaGerada();
    }  
}
```

## Melhorando o código

Eu não entendi qual é a sua ideia com a `chave` e com o `Map`, mas há alguns elementos nos quais as chaves colidem. Por exemplo:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9] - chave = 124
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10] - chave = 124

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9] - chave = 109
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7] - chave = 109

[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9] - chave = 123
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9] - chave = 123
```

Este código no final das contas vai mostrar onde ocorrem essas colisões dessas chaves, mostrando os 71 lugares que as tem (esse é o tamanho final).

Considerando que o resultado que você almeja na tabela que está na sua pergunta, não acho que esse procedimento do método `parsearListaGerada` faça sentido para você. Se entendi a sua pergunta direito, o que você quer é eliminar resultados que tenham 5 ou mais números repetidos. Esse método no entanto apenas mostra quais são os volantes que tem chaves colidindo. Acabei jogando fora este método.

Para refazer tudo, primeiro vamos introduzir uma classe `Volante`:

```
    private static final class Volante {
        private final Set<Integer> numeros;

        public Volante(int[] valores) {
            this.numeros = IntStream.of(valores).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        }

        public int dissimilaridade(Volante outro) {
            List<Integer> interseccao = new ArrayList<>(numeros);
            interseccao.removeAll(outro.numeros);
            return interseccao.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return numeros.toString();
        }
    }
```

O nome da classe é autoexplicativo. O construtor dela converte um `int[]` em um `Set<Integer>`. A grande sacada é o método `dissimilaridade(Volante)` que mede quantos números diferem entre um volante e outro.

Com isso, podemos fazer o seguinte método:

```
    private static List<Volante> limitarSimilaridade(List<Volante> volantes, int dissimilaridadeMinima) {
        List<Volante> dissimilares = new ArrayList<>(volantes.size());

        externo:
        for (Volante volante : volantes) {
            for (Volante dejaVu : dissimilares) {
                if (volante.dissimilaridade(dejaVu) < dissimilaridadeMinima) continue externo;
            }
            dissimilares.add(volante);
        }
        return dissimilares;
    }
```

Este método obtém uma lista de `Volante`s e devolve uma outra lista filtrada removendo aqueles que são parecidos demais entre si. Por "parecidos demais" entenda-se que tenham uma dissimilaridade abaixo do valor especificado com algum outro volante da lista.

Este é o código completo do que fiz:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public final class Combinacoes {

    private static final class Volante {
        private final Set<Integer> numeros;

        public Volante(int[] valores) {
            this.numeros = IntStream.of(valores).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
        }

        public int dissimilaridade(Volante outro) {
            List<Integer> interseccao = new ArrayList<>(numeros);
            interseccao.removeAll(outro.numeros);
            return interseccao.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return numeros.toString();
        }
    }

    public static List<Volante> busca(int quantidade, int numeros) {
        List<Volante> volantes = new ArrayList<>();
        busca(volantes, new int[quantidade], 0, numeros - quantidade, 0);
        return volantes;
    }

    private static void busca(List<Volante> volantes, int[] resultado, int inicio, int fim, int profundidade) {
        for (int x = inicio; x <= fim; x++) {
            resultado[profundidade] = x + 1;
            if (profundidade + 1 >= resultado.length) {
                volantes.add(new Volante(resultado));
            } else {
                busca(volantes, resultado, x + 1, fim + 1, profundidade + 1);
            }
        }
    }  

    private static List<Volante> limitarSimilaridade(List<Volante> volantes, int dissimilaridadeMinima) {
        List<Volante> dissimilares = new ArrayList<>(volantes.size());

        externo:
        for (Volante volante : volantes) {
            for (Volante dejaVu : dissimilares) {
                if (volante.dissimilaridade(dejaVu) < dissimilaridadeMinima) continue externo;
            }
            dissimilares.add(volante);
        }
        return dissimilares;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        List<Volante> volantes = busca(6, 10);
        System.out.println(volantes.toString().replace("], ", "]\n"));
        System.out.println("Total de combinacoes: " + volantes.size());

        List<Volante> filtrados = limitarSimilaridade(volantes, 2);
        System.out.println("Tamanho final: " + filtrados.size());
        System.out.println("Resultado final");
        System.out.println(filtrados.toString().replace("], ", "]\n"));
    }  
}
```

Como você pode ver, fiz mais algumas outras alterações no código além das que listei acima. Basicamente a ideia era:

- Deixar os campos úteis apenas no método `busca` viverem apenas dentro desse método.
- Produzir listas como resultado dos métodos ao invés de apenas armazená-las.

Ao executar esse novo programa, eis o final da saída (após mostrar os 210 volantes gerados):

```
Tamanho final:18
Resultado final
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 10]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9]
[1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10]
[3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

Essa é exatamente a mesma lista que você colocou na sua pergunta e que você esperava ter como resposta.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/8H0vC3)

Comment: meu muito obrigado, vou fazer uma analise mais me parece correto.